# Loop through returned JSON from an API

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, api, json.net

I have the following JSON in asp.net VB:

```
Dim jsonString As String = "{'results':[ {'comments':  'some text', 'date'   : 'some date', 'user':'aaa'},{'comments':  'some text2', 'date2'   : 'some date2', 'user':'aaa2'}]} "

Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
```

How can I loop though the values like comments?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you read the Newtonsoft documentation pages [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) and [Querying JSON with SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)?

Comment: I actually figured that out. But this works only on framework 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Dim jsonString As String = "{'results':[ {'comments':  'some text', 'date'   : 'some date', 'user':'aaa'},{'comments':  'some text2', 'date2'   : 'some date2', 'user':'aaa2'}]} "
Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)

Dim commToken As JToken
Dim commValue As String
For Each Row In json("results").ToList()
    commToken = Row("comments")
    commValue = DirectCast(commToken, JValue).Value
Next

Comment: If you need to include additional example code in your question, please [edit] your question and include it there, properly formatted.  Don't include it in comments.  For more see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The Newtonsoft documentation pages [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) and [Querying JSON with SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) describe how you can query for values nested inside a `JObject` hierarchy once loaded.

For instance, using [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm), you can query for the comment values as follows:

```
' Get all comment values, convert them to simple strings, and store in an array:
Dim comments = json.SelectTokens("results[*].comments") _
    .Select(Function(t) t.ToString()) _
    .ToArray()
```

Here I am using the wildcard operator `[*]` to match all elements in the `"results"` array.  This is a standard operator of [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) which `SelectTokens()` supports.

Here is the equivalent logic using LINQ:

```
Dim query = From item In json("results")
    Let comment = item("comments")
    Where comment IsNot Nothing
    Select CType(comment, String)               
Dim comments = query.ToArray()
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKzu9F).